# How do I get this Anchor tag to fill the space before the next div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to create a bootstrap drop down box with some additional buttons inside. I have the main functionality sorted but the aesthetics are not quite right.

The issue I am having is that the Anchor elements are not filling the space up to the buttons on the right. I have tried experimenting with different combinations of `block` and `inline-block` which I have read elsewhere should fill the space but when it does it pushes the buttons down to the next line. When I do manage to get the buttons and anchor elements on the same line the selection area for the anchor does not extend the entire way up to the buttons.

I am currently tearing my hair out trying to get it to work but am having no luck so if anyone can offer any assistance it will be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Thanks to @Matus Jurika for suggesting using `calc` to adjust the sizing of the anchor element.

Updated working fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3fra0bm/35/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sugget using calc for width:

```
.anchorDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 74px);
}
```

Working Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/q3fra0bm/36/

Comment: Thank you for the response @Matus Jurika. It had never occurred to me to use calc in the sizing. Seeing as my buttons div will always be a fixed size this seems to make the most sense. Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best solutions so therefore I am marking this as the answer

Comment: Note: The fiddle that has been linked doesn't reflect what has been suggested in the answer but once implemented it does work

Comment: Sorry my bad, I updated fiddle now. Glad I helped though.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
.comboItemContainer {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.anchorDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 80px 0 0;
}

.comboButtons {
    width: 74px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

I made the container relative so that I can freely use absolute positioning on its children with a (0,0) origin relative to the container. Then I made the buttons absolute, made it top 0 and right 0. Added 100% width on the anchor and 80px padding-right.

This may look hacky but I'm not really that good in Flex and absolutely zero in Grid

This is almost certainly cross browser though

Comment: Thanks for the response @Merigold, this answer is definitely an option I could use and does achieve what I am after. However, due to it's simplicity, I am marking Matus Jurika's answer as the accepted one. This was a close second though.

Comment: Every day is a school day @Merigold!

Answer (score 0):

This here is snippet for your solution. I am just using bootstrap `row` class.

```css
.comboRow {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.comboItem {
    display: block !important;
    /*width: 67%;*/
}

.comboButtons {
    float:right;
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 74px;
    display: block;
}

.comboItemContainer {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.anchorDiv {
    display: inline-block;
}

.close {
    /*float: right;*/
    /*margin-right: 10px;*/
}

.close .edit {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#presetDropdownButton {
    position:absolute;
}

.glyphicon {
    font-size: 15px;
}

#presetDropdown {
    width: max-content;
}

#newPresetEntry {
    width: 50%;
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > div > div > a {
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > div > div > a:focus {
    color: #262626;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > div > div > a:hover {
    color: #262626;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.pl-0 {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}
.pr-0 {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="dropdown" id="presetDropdownButton">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Presets
  <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="presetDropdown">
    <li class="comboRow">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9 pr-0">
          <a class="comboItem" href="#" value="1">Preset 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 pl-0">
          <button type="button" class="close deletePreset" aria-label="Delete" style="margin-right: 10px;">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="close edit editPreset" aria-label="Edit" style="margin-right: 3px;">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&#9998;</span>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="close edit savePreset" aria-label="Save" style="margin-right: 3px;">
            <span style="font-size: 18px;" aria-hidden="true">&#128190;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="comboRow">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9 pr-0">
          <a class="comboItem" href="#" value="1">Preset 2 with longer name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 pl-0">
          <button type="button" class="close deletePreset" aria-label="Delete" style="margin-right: 10px;">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="close edit editPreset" aria-label="Edit" style="margin-right: 3px;">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&#9998;</span>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="close edit savePreset" aria-label="Save" style="margin-right: 3px;">
            <span style="font-size: 18px;" aria-hidden="true">&#128190;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="comboRow">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9 pr-0">
          <a class="comboItem" href="#" value="1">Preset 3 with even longer name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 pl-0">
          <button type="button" class="close deletePreset" aria-label="Delete" style="margin-right: 10px;">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="close edit editPreset" aria-label="Edit" style="margin-right: 3px;">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&#9998;</span>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="close edit savePreset" aria-label="Save" style="margin-right: 3px;">
            <span style="font-size: 18px;" aria-hidden="true">&#128190;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Hamid R. I've never had any experience with boostrap rows before but it looks like an interesting concept. From running the snippet it doesn't seem to display the icons quite right but that could be down to a browser incompatibility issue (I am using Chrome). This will surely be something I keep in mind for when I next need to arrange items using rows and columns